# Kotlin jetpack compose impossible to compile Backend Exception

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

my project does not compile with this stacktrace:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: myApp/navigation/NavGraph.kt
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:239)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:235)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.doGenerateFilesInternal(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:195)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:331)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:170)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while generating code for:
FUN name:SetupNavGraph visibility:public modality:FINAL <> (navController:androidx.navigation.NavHostController, viewModel:androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel, $composer:androidx.compose.runtime.Composer?, $changed:kotlin.Int) returnType:kotlin.Unit
```

With my class being

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: ViewModel
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Splash.route
    ) {
        composable(
            route = Screen.Splash.route
        ) {
            SplashScreen(
                navController = navController,
                viewModel = viewModel as MainActivityViewModel
            )
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.Map.route
        ) {
            MapScreen(
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I do not find any hint online and don't know what to do.
Note that the project compiled at least once before and my current work does not touch this kotlin file.

Comment: This is a painful issue yet a funny one, different solutions has different effect on people's case, I encountered one when I modify a data class property from `val` to `var`, I was able to reproduce it multiple times to verify that its the issue and it was the culprit!, I have no idea how it's happening, so maybe you can check your history somewhere, and try to slowly get back to those old states of the files/classes/methods etc...

Comment: but i was developing a huge change (more or less 600 line of code) there has to be a better approach...hopefully

Comment: ohh, I see, mine is a little bit odd, though I can't reproduce it now since the code was entirely changed, maybe you can try playing around the kotlin and compose versions?, I checked the top result in google and saw an S.O post with different solutions, maybe you can pick some from those, oh wait, do you have a file named "NavGraph" ?, would mind trying to change it with some other unique name?

Comment: yes, NavGraph is mine, there is no compilation error (at least does not pop out anything) but the stacktrace seems to stop compiling that file

Comment: try changing the file name to something unique, this might waste your time but you can try if you want, just mess up the codes inside of it a little bit, names of functions, variables etc… if nothing works just ignore everything I said and apologies in advance..

Comment: @z.y nope, nothing changes